# Unable to change the date format to the yyyy-mm-dd h-m-s

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Below is the dataframe df as below

```
    RT_Date             DateCreated
0   1/2/21 6:38         01-31-2021 14:38:12
1   1/2/21 2:58         01-31-2021 10:57:50
2   02-19-2021 17:59:00 02-19-2021 17:59:29
3   9/2/21 12:49        9/2/21 11:35
```

I've written a code which checks if there's a 30 minutes difference between RT_Date and DateCreated i.e RT_Date - DateCreated = 30min difference. Below is the code

```
df['RT_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RT_Date'])
df['DateCreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCreated'])

df['RT_Date'] = df['RT_Date'].dt.time
df['DateCreated'] = df['DateCreated'].dt.time

df['RT_Date'] = df['RT_Date'].astype(str)
df['DateCreated'] = df['DateCreated'].astype(str)

df['RT_Date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['RT_Date'])
df['DateCreated'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DateCreated'])

df['Diff'] = df['RT_Date'] - df['DateCreated']

df['Diff'] = df['Diff'].dt.total_seconds()

df['Diff'] = df['Diff']/60

df['Diff'] = df['Diff'].astype(int)

df['Diff'] = df['Diff'].abs()

df['Diff'] = df['Diff'].apply(lambda x: x <= 30)
```

And below is the output

```
    RT_Date         DateCreated     Diff
0   0 days 06:38:00 0 days 14:38:12 False
1   0 days 02:58:00 0 days 10:57:50 False
2   0 days 17:59:00 0 days 17:59:29 True
3   0 days 12:49:00 0 days 11:35:00 False
```

In the above output, i'm confused why it's taking as 0 days. Can anyone rectify this error??

Comment: You converted the dates to timedeltas.  That's not the correct procedure.  Timedeltas are created when you subtract two datetime objects.

Comment: @TimRoberts Not really, he creates timedelta from the time of date.

Comment: What's the alternative code for this??

Comment: Ah, you're right, but it's that conversion to a `time` object that drops the dates.  Just delete the third through sixth lines.  Do the conversion to datetime, and then just subtract the datetime columns.

Comment: which code? the dt.time or astype(str) or timedelta? Can you please write

Comment: @NithinReddy Not sure what you want, but you can try `df['Diff'] = df['RT_Date'].sub(df['DateCreated']).dt.total_seconds().div(60).abs().le(30)` after `pd.to_datetime`